# Dot and Cross product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, transpose

I have the following matrix multiplication

$$ \left(\begin{matrix} -3&2 \\ 5&-3  \\ \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} \cdot\left(\begin{matrix} 1&4&0 \\ 1 & 1&-2  \\ \end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left[\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 4\\3 \end{matrix}\right)\wedge\left(\begin{matrix} 5 \\ 2\\-1 \end{matrix}\right)\right]$$

For the inverse I get:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)$$

And the cross product leaves me with:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} -10 \\ 16\\-18 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Now it should look like the following:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 3 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&4&0 \\ 1 & 1&-2 \end{matrix}\right)\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix} -10 \\16 \\-18 \end{matrix}\right)$$

This is my current thinking but I have to be making an error since I'm getting the wrong answer.

Hopefuly showing step-by-step helps identifying my error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a mess, i'm trying to fix my syntax!

Comment: You may find this useful: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry guys. For some reason irrespective of what post I click on all math-syntax is showin instead of the matrices and what not. So if this looks weird to you I am unfortunately not able to fix it.

Comment: Cheers. I thought it would enlarge the cross since it should denote the cross product operation between the matrices.

Comment: the first two matrices yields a $2\times3$ matrix so the cross-product of the last two column matrices(those within the parentheses) have to be tranposed into a $3\times1$. Yes "$X$" is the cross-product of the two last matrices.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you @Jean-ClaudeArbaut.

Comment: I think I finally got the question right. Can you check?

Comment: And what is the right answer?